# Gradle sync fail for a Grails project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, grails

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3 and having trouble with a basic project in Grails in it - when Gradle starts syncing the project after starting up the IDE, all the checkmarks are green and labeled as "OK", my Messages tab is empty but still I get an alert on top of the editing pane reading "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editting, debugging) will not work properly".

I've tried removing the `.gradle` folder, the Restart and Invalidate option, giving IntelliJ a local path to Gradle as opposed to just telling it to use the default - all to no avail. I'm behind a corporate proxy but it is set up in IntelliJ so it shouldn't be blocking anything (especially since all the syncing seems to be working just fine).

What could be the problem? Versions of my stack:

```
Grails Version: 3.3.8
Groovy Version: 2.4.15
JVM Version: 1.8.0_181
Gradle Version: 3.5
```

I've tried ensuring that proxy's not the problem according to @dkb suggestion but it does not seem to be malfunctioning - I did Invalidate and Restart again and after running `bootRun`, Gradle correctly downloaded Apache Ant to run the application so it doesn't seem likely to be the culprit here.

IntelliJ also kept nagging me for Android SDK (who knows why but OK) which I could not install "normally" in the corporate setting but in the end I did provide it through IDEA's `Settings -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> Edit` and downloading some arbitrary API and the SDK tools through there so it shouldn't be the problem either (or at least I presume it shouldn't).

In line with @y.bedrov's suggestion, I am attaching [the log after reproducing the issue](https://wtools.io/paste-code/Ca) (external link cause it exceeds SO's post character limits).

Comment: you can check in console whether gradle is able to download dependencies from Internet, if not then the proxy is not working.

Comment: @dkb - Oh, how can I test it then, to make sure dependencies downloading isn't the problem? What command would be the most sensible to rule that out?

Comment: go to a terminal, execute suitable build command for your project.

Comment: @dkb - doesn't seem to be the problem, edited it into the original question

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: @y.bedrov - sure, added it in! (barring the first few lines with things like version numbers info because I couldn't fit it into 30k characters otherwise)

Comment: Reformatted the question a little and provided the full log instead of the truncated version

Comment: I had the same error in IDEA 2019.1 on using gradle 5 and gradle 4. The error went away on using gradle 3.